# Gift for 16 year old Aspiring astrophysicist,,,,

Tags: astrophysics

I'm an outsider here, so please bear with me.
I have a 16-year-old nephew interested in the field of astrophysics and am looking for a birthday gift.  I had thought about a book on astronomy, but don't see that field listed as a core pre-requisite for that career.  Is knowledge of astronomy a core pre-requisite/useful for this profession?
Thank you

Comment: One of Richard Feynman's books. e.g "Six easy pieces" or "Six not so easy pieces". Setting out in Feynman's footsteps is always a good plan.

Comment: Astrophysics is physics.  Starting out a solid interest in basic physics is a necessity.  Everything else you can pick up.  I'd honestly suggest a book token - let them pick their own book or books - they'll know what they want.

Comment: Randal Munroe (author of xkcd) has books not directly related to astronomy but to science and shows therein typical approach to thorough scientific answering methods. Otherwise Feynman and or Hawking are good candidates

Comment: A really beginner scope? Don't stick too much on the word. Astronomy oriented gifts could be fine.

Comment: If he does not have a telescope you can maybe buy one ? I think he would love that. Or theres a book called "Cosmology for the Curious" by Delia Perlov · Alex Vilenkin. It's a great book for high school level.

Answer (score 2):

there is a series of educational Japanese manga comics books called "The Manga Guides" they explain a particular subject of science and maths (like Physics, Relativity, Regression Analysis, Statistics, etc) and they are fun to read, I gifted the one on Physics to my 14-year old nephew and he liked it. Also the book has actual exercises between chapters and explained examples, and each book are independent, so you are not obligated to read all of them to finish the story.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Manga_Guides#The_Manga_Guide_to_Physics

There is one on the Universe and General Relativity too. I read the one on Relativity out of curiosity and it was very entertaining